# Symfony2 app_dev.php only error 500 Premature end of script

Tags: php, symfony, permissions, apache2, debian

I has problem with Symfony2. All work fine, and one day... start the problems ...

When i open a page, i get error 500. The server return this error, not Symfony.
If i refresh, I display display the page without error.
But when i open a new page (new url, same site), the error come again.

I tried to reload apache. I tried remove all in cache and logs.
My console file, app.php file, app_dev.php file have umask(0000) uncommented.

This is the last line of symfony2 logs when i have the error :

```
[2015-09-04 11:20:57] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.response" to listener "JMS\I18nRoutingBundle\EventListener\CookieSettingListener::onKernelResponse". [] []
[2015-09-04 11:20:57] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.response" to listener "Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Firewall\ContextListener::onKernelResponse". [] []
[2015-09-04 11:20:57] security.DEBUG: Write SecurityContext in the session [] []
[2015-09-04 11:20:57] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.response" to listener "Symfony\Bridge\Monolog\Handler\FirePHPHandler::onKernelResponse". [] []
[2015-09-04 11:20:57] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.response" to listener "Symfony\Bridge\Monolog\Handler\ChromePhpHandler::onKernelResponse". [] []
[2015-09-04 11:20:57] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.response" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\ResponseListener::onKernelResponse". [] []
[2015-09-04 11:20:57] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.response" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\EsiListener::onKernelResponse". [] []
[2015-09-04 11:20:57] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.response" to listener "Symfony\Component\Security\Http\RememberMe\ResponseListener::onKernelResponse". [] []
[2015-09-04 11:20:57] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.response" to listener "Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\EventListener\HttpCacheListener::onKernelResponse". [] []
[2015-09-04 11:20:57] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.response" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\ProfilerListener::onKernelResponse". [] []
[2015-09-04 11:20:57] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.response" to listener "Symfony\Bundle\WebProfilerBundle\EventListener\WebDebugToolbarListener::onKernelResponse". [] []
[2015-09-04 11:20:57] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.response" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\SaveSessionListener::onKernelResponse". [] []
[2015-09-04 11:20:57] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.response" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\StreamedResponseListener::onKernelResponse". [] []
[2015-09-04 11:20:57] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.terminate" to listener "Symfony\Bundle\SwiftmailerBundle\EventListener\EmailSenderListener::onTerminate". [] []
```

The apache error log :

```
[Fri Sep 04 11:24:49 2015] [error] [client my.ip.here] Premature end of script headers: app_dev.php
```

The problem does not exist in prod, when i use app.php

The syslog does not have line about this. I don't have problem on other website on the same server. I don't have hard drive space problem.

Anyone have an idea ? thx

---

The app_dev.php file :

```
<?php


use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Debug\Debug;


// If you don't want to setup permissions the proper way, just uncomment the following PHP line
// read http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/installation.html#configuration-and-setup for more information
umask(0000);

// This check prevents access to debug front controllers that are deployed by accident to production servers.
// Feel free to remove this, extend it, or make something more sophisticated.
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])
    || isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])
    || !in_array(@$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], array('127.0.0.1', 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx'))
) {
    header('HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden');
    exit($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'].' : You are not allowed to access this file. Check '.basename(__FILE__).' for more information.');
}

$loader = require_once __DIR__.'/../app/bootstrap.php.cache';
Debug::enable();

require_once __DIR__.'/../app/AppKernel.php';

$kernel = new AppKernel('dev', true);
$kernel->loadClassCache();
$request = Request::createFromGlobals();
$response = $kernel->handle($request);
$response->send();
$kernel->terminate($request, $response);
```

---

For apache configuration, it's isp config configuration, i just added this for this website :

Apache directive :

```
DocumentRoot /var/www/clients/client2/web56/web/symfony/web/
FcgidMaxRequestLen 20000000
```

php.ini :

```
apc.shm_size = 256M
realpath_cache_size = 4096k
realpath_cache_ttl=7200
session.auto_start = 0
xdebug.remote_autostart=0
xdebug.remote_enable=0
xdebug.profiler_enable=0
```

---

In config_dev.yml, if I remove firephp and chromephp from monolog configuration, the problem is solved.
I don't think it's good solution, anyone have an other idea ?

Comment: Could you please past app_dev.php file and your apache configuration?

Comment: That error can be number of things. See this link: http://www.liquidweb.com/kb/apache-error-premature-end-of-script-headers/

Comment: I have posted my app_dev.php file.

Comment: In config_dev.yml, if I remove firephp and chromephp from monolog configuration, the problem is solved.
I don't think it's good solution, anyone have an other idea ?

Comment: I have the same problem and the same fix works for me. Very strange. Didn't ever used firephp and chromephp, so it's not a real problem to disable them. Nevertheless, it's strange that such a fix is necessary.

Comment: I solved the same issue in the same way, but I still have no idea about why this fixed... and what it was actually fixed

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I have commented **firephp** and **chromephp** in **config_dev.yml** :

```
imports:
    - { resource: config.yml }

framework:
    router:
        resource: "%kernel.root_dir%/config/routing_dev.yml"
        strict_requirements: true
    profiler: { only_exceptions: false }

web_profiler:
    toolbar: true
    intercept_redirects: false

monolog:
    handlers:
        main:
            type:  stream
            path:  "%kernel.logs_dir%/%kernel.environment%.log"
            level: debug
#        firephp:
#            type:  firephp
#            level: info
#        chromephp:
#            type:  chromephp
#            level: info

assetic:
    use_controller: true

#swiftmailer:
#    delivery_address: me@example.com
```